# Bootstrap Navbar is disappearing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I'm using Bootstrap 5 with my navbar but whenever I look at it with a mobile view then the buttons disappear. Hovering over it won't show anything either. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark hover-shadow" style="background-color: #252c3a;" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pK7YWmW.png" height="60" width="212" alt="Server Knight profile picture.">
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active navbar-btn"
                        href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=801424420605263902&permissions=8589934591&scope=bot">Invite
                        me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active navbar-btn" href="https://discord.gg/yAd6Y2GcTe">DSOF</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link active navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        About the bot
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-background" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-btn" href="/docs">Docs</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider" style="border-color: #fff">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-btn" href="/faq">Faq</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider" style="border-color: #fff">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-btn" href="/team">The team</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link active navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Applications
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-background" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-btn" href="/appeal">Appeal a report</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider" style="border-color: #fff">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-btn" href="/apply">Apply to be a bot developer</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active navbar-btn" href="/donate">Donate</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <a href="/login" class="login-btn nav-link active" id="login-btn">Login</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwgbpeqj/1/)

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You're using navbar-expand-xl which means it will collapse to mobile on less than xl screen width

Comment: Oh really, I didn't know that tbh

Comment: I got your issue. You need to add media queries in your navbar tag. In the bootstrap documentation, you will find the media queries for all the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is as commented this line:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark hover-shadow" style="background-color: #252c3a;" role="navigation">
```

Like said on [Bootstraps documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/) the navbar will only display on xl devices (1200px width), if you want it to be shown on mobile as well remove the `navbar-expand-xl` from it.